# How to take every possible n-size square from PNG file with PIL?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I want to load image, crop every possible square of given size(taken from user) from png file and print average RGB values for every given crop. Right now my code looks like this:

```
from PIL import Image
from statistics import mean

print("Input height: ")
crop_height = int(input())

print("Input width: ")
crop_width = int(input())
image = Image.open('daisy/5547758_eea9edfd54_n.jpg')
print(image.size)
image_height, image_width = image.size
for y in range(0, image_height-crop_height):
    for x in range(0, image_width-crop_width):
        box = (x, y, crop_width, crop_height)
        print(box)
        cropped_image = image.crop(box)
        average_color = [round(mean(cropped_image.getdata(band))) for band in range(3)]
        print("RGB: ", average_color)
```

I test this for 32x32 square. How can I do this ? Right now I get this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\testMap\RGBAvg.py", line 19, in <module>
    average_color = [round(mean(cropped_image.getdata(band))) for band in range(3)]
  File "C:\Users\Damian\PycharmProjects\testMap\RGBAvg.py", line 19, in <listcomp>
    average_color = [round(mean(cropped_image.getdata(band))) for band in range(3)]
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\statistics.py", line 315, in mean
    raise StatisticsError('mean requires at least one data point')
statistics.StatisticsError: mean requires at least one data point
```

Comment: This needs debugging. Obviously, `mean()` does not like whatever it is that you are passing to it. So what *are* you passing to it? Find out! Is is what you were expecting? If not, where did it come from? How was it computed? Why does that computation not yield the expected results? Etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing an empty list to `mean()` - get the list and check its length before passing to `mean()` and break out of your loop if it is empty.